# What is the equivalent of newSessionStore in wicket 1.5.7?

Tags: wicket-1.5

newSessionStore() method is removed from wicket 1.5.

```
@Override
protected ISessionStore newSessionStore()
{
 return new HttpSessionStore(this);
}
```

what is the equivalent of this method in 1.5?

Answer (score 0):

According to [migration guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/migration-to-wicket-15.html) there's no equivalent in Wicket 1.5. Only HttpSessionStore is supported

Comment: it is quite easy please refer this link http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Equivalent-of-newSessionStore-in-wicket-1-5-7-td4651078.html